# How to select rows where a value has changed, an item is new for a date or leaves from previous date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Okay, I was able to implement parts of this question independently, but I can't seem to combine them.

My table looks something like this

```
THING  | ID1 | ID2 | VALUE |     DATE
-------------------------------------
thing1 |  a1 |  1a |     5 | 20190605
thing2 |  a2 |  2c |    10 | 20190605
thing4 |  a5 |  3x |     7 | 20190605
thing1 |  a1 |  1a |     6 | 20190606
thing2 |  a2 |  2c |    10 | 20160606
thing3 |  a3 |  2b |     3 | 20160606
```

But has thousands of elements per day and eight or nine identifiers, but once we get a solution down, I can extrapolate.

I want to be able to return any element that has it's `VALUE` changed day over day, or is a new element that didn't exist the previous day. I also want to be able to see what the value was the previous day, so it should be `NULL` if it didn't exist, and it should be the previous day's value if it did. I also want to see in the same manner, elements that existed the previous day that no longer exist today. The result of my query is going to be some sort of outer join on the table and an `EXISTS` check somewhere...

The query will return from the table above, the below.

```
 THING | ID1 | ID2 | VALUE | YDAY_VALUE |     DATE
--------------------------------------------------
thing1 |  a1 |  1a |     6 |          5 | 20190606
thing4 |  a5 |  3x |  NULL |          7 | 20190606
thing3 |  a3 |  2b |     3 |       NULL | 20190606
```

I can do this just checkiing any one of the three things but I'm at my wits' end trying to chain them.

Thanks for your help guys. It's always much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will work for a fixed date:

```
select 
a.thing, a.ID1, a.ID2, a.value, b.value as YDAY_VALUE, a.date
from test a, test b
where a.thing = b.thing and 
a.ID1 = b.ID1 and 
a.ID2 = b.ID2 and 
a.date = b.date+1
union select
a.thing, a.ID1, a.ID2, a.value, null as YDAY_VALUE, a.date
from test a where a.date ="20190606" and  a.thing not in (select  b.thing from test b
where a.thing = b.thing and 
a.ID1 = b.ID1 and 
a.ID2 = b.ID2 and 
b.date="20190605")
union select
a.thing, a.ID1, a.ID2, null as value, a.value as YDAY_VALUE, a.date
from test a where a.date ="20190605" and  a.thing not in (select  b.thing from test b
where a.thing = b.thing and 
a.ID1 = b.ID1 and 
a.ID2 = b.ID2 and 
b.date="20190606")
 ;
```

however if you try to extrapolate for any dates, it might duplicate your empty/non-matching records - watch out for that - like changing the condition as below will give you today record that are abandoned and yesterday records that are abandoned. But maybe it's beyond your scope.

```
union select
a.thing, a.ID1, a.ID2, a.value, null as YDAY_VALUE, a.date
from test a where a.thing not in (select  b.thing from test b
where a.thing = b.thing and 
a.ID1 = b.ID1 and 
a.ID2 = b.ID2 and 
a.date = b.date+1)
```

Comment: This, this is much closer to what I'm looking for, much of what you've got is going to help me out. I hadn't considered simply making three separate queries to return only a small part of what I want and then performing the union

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a `join`:

```
select t.*, tprev.value as prev_value
from t full join
     t tprev
     on t.thing = tprev.thing and
        t.id1 = tprev.id1 and
        t.id2 = tprev.id2 and
        t.date = dateadd(day, 1, tprev.date)
where tprev.thing is null or
      tnext.thing is null or
      tprev.value <> t.value;
```

Comment: Will the left join also show elements that don't exist in `20190606` but did exist in `20190605`?

Comment: @DanWhite . . . Your question only mentions the previous day, but I do see that your sample data includes both days, so I modified the answer.

Comment: Nah. not even close. Nowhere do you specify the date either. Assume that the table extends indefinitely in both directions for the date.